# How to implement a pull-down button that supports multiple selection?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton, uimenu

I had no trouble implementing a pop-up button that lets a user select from a mutually exclusive list of options. This is covered in the [Pop-up buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/pop-up-buttons) section of the HIG.

Now I want something similar but to allow the user to select any number of options from the list. The "Pop-up buttons" page in the HIG states:

> Use a pull-down button instead if you need to: [...] Let people select multiple items

But the [Pull-down buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/pull-down-buttons) page of the HIG makes no mention of how to support multiple selection.

Here's what I tried so far. I start with the pop-up button code (copy and paste into an iOS Swift Playground to play along):

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let items = [ "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4" ]
        let actions: [UIAction] = items.map {
            let action = UIAction(title: $0) { action in
                print("Selected \(action.title)")
            }

            return action
        }
        let menu = UIMenu(children: actions)

        var buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.gray()
        let button = UIButton(configuration: buttonConfig)
        button.menu = menu
        button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        button.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyVC()
```

Then update the code to make it a pull-down button. First, disable the `changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction` property of the button.

```
button.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = false
```

Then give the button a title so it appears as more than a tiny little square.

```
buttonConfig.title = "Select Items"
```

Now we have a button that shows a menu when it's tapped. But now there are no checkmarks and selecting a menu doesn't result in any checkmark. So here I thought I would update the handler block of the `UIAction` to toggle the action's `state`.

```swift
let action = UIAction(title: $0) { action in
    print("Selected \(action.title)")
    action.state = action.state == .on ? .off : .on
}
```

But now when you tap on a menu item the code crashes with an exception. When running in a real iOS app (not a Playground), the error is:

> 2023-05-21 10:40:56.038217-0600 ButtonMenu[63482:10716279] *** Assertion failure in -[_UIImmutableAction setState:], UIAction.m:387
> 2023-05-21 10:40:56.063676-0600 ButtonMenu[63482:10716279] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Action is immutable because it is a child of a menu'

Is it possible to implement a multiple select menu using `UIButton` and `UIMenu`?

If so, what piece am I missing?

If not, what component should be used for multiple selection? Ideally it would be great if the user could tap the button to bring up the menu, select multiple items in the menu, then tap the button again to dismiss the menu.

Comment: Did you try keepsMenuPresented for the UIAction attributes? It works in iOS 16.

Comment: @Don I just tried that. It does keep the menu presented allowing for easy multiple selection. However, the checkmarks don't change until the menu is dismissed and presented again. At least with the code in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around. Instead of trying to modify the `action` provided in the `UIAction` handler, you need to modify the original action in the button's menu.

The problem is that you can't get the `UIMenu` from the `UIAction`. And you can't declare the `UIMenu` before creating the array of `UIAction`. So you need to create the `UIButton` first, then you can access the button in the action handler which then lets you access the button's menu and update the matching action.

Here's updated code that allows you to select multiple items in a pull-down menu:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.gray()
        buttonConfig.title = "Select Stuff"
        let button = UIButton(configuration: buttonConfig)

        let items = [ "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4" ]
        let actions: [UIAction] = items.map {
            let action = UIAction(title: $0) { action in
                print("Selected \(action.title)")

                // The following line causes a crash
                //action.state = action.state == .on ? .off : .on

                // The following updates the original UIAction without crashing
                if let act = button.menu?.children.first(where: { $0.title == action.title }), let act = act as? UIAction {
                    act.state = act.state == .on ? .off : .on
                }
            }

            // This keeps the menu presented allowing for multiple selection
            // but the checkmark state doesn't update until the menu
            // is dismissed and displayed again.
            // action.attributes = [ .keepsMenuPresented ]

            return action
        }

        let menu = UIMenu(children: actions)
        button.menu = menu
        button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyVC()
```

Now that I finally figured out how to make this work, I realize it has two big user experience issues. 1) The button doesn't reflect the current selection state like the pop-up button does. 2) If the user wants to select more than one item, the user needs to tap the button to present the menu for each desired selection.

Issue 1 can be solved by adding the following line inside the action handler, after the code that updates the action's state:

```
button.configuration?.title = button.menu?.selectedElements.map { $0.title }.joined(separator: ", ") ?? "None"
```

Issue 2 can be solved, sort of, by adding the `.keepsMenuPresented` attribute to each of the `UIAction` instances. While doing this allows the user to tap on multiple actions while the menu stays presented, the checkmark state of the actions does not change until the menu is dismissed and presented again.

---

The original question and this answer don't address one other real-world part of this task - having some of the menu items selected initially. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like the stuff in the pop-up menu section of the HIG about using the pull-down menu for multiple selection is just blowing chunks. Not the first time I've seen that happen in Apple's docs, WWDC videos, etc.

I would suggest just using a different interface, i.e. don't try to do this with the built-in button -> UIMenu interface.

Instead, when the user does whatever the user should do (tap the button), you present a presented view controller; now you're in charge of the interface, and you can use a multiple-selection table view, a table view with switches, whatever. (You can see some rather old discussion about some of the options [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/87848/what-control-should-i-use-to-indicate-multi-select-lists-on-ios).) The presented view can be at any size and location; I like to use a popover presentation for this sort of thing.

I think that's better than "fighting the framework".

Comment: Actually, I'm currently presenting a table view with the list of options. I was replacing that code to use a pop-up button for the single-select cases. It looks better on an iPad with the button menu rather than having the table view appear in a popup. This is especially true running on a Mac via Catalyst. I was hoping to make the same change for cases where the user could select more than one option. Time will tell which approach I settle on. The question ultimately stems from the simple question of "can it be done or not?" rather than "should it be done?".

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you. At the very least I'd recommend filing an enhancement request with Apple. This should be easy.